# Maven dependency has no jar in the central repo and the maven build fails due to no artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I added this dependency to my pom.xml. When I build the project if creates this error.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-sandbox-parent</artifactId>
  <version>10</version>
</dependency>
```

Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.name:core:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.commons:commons-sandbox-parent:jar:10 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

When I follow this link to the central repo, I notice that there are no precompiled jar files the folder. The build process complains about no jar. All the other dependencies I use have precompiled jar files in them. How can I solve this and compile my project?

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-sandbox-parent/10/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dependency is of type 'pom', not type 'jar'. It's mentioned in the 'packaging' tag in the pom file at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-sandbox-parent/10/commons-sandbox-parent-10.pom.

If no type is specified while declaring a dependency it assumes it to be 'jar'. You can specify the type 'pom' instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-sandbox-parent</artifactId>
  <version>10</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello. I have made the chance and the error went away. However i cannot use the package it was supposed to add to my project. I cannot find any compiled project or class from the commons-sandbox-parent. How do I add the compiled jar package to my project.

Comment: Could you specify which class/classes you need from the sandbox jar?

Comment: Hi, I need the Id classes to generate version 1 uuid. http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-id/uuid.html

Comment: There's UUID class in jdk itself http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html which you can use. 
Searching in maven by class returned this jar http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.littleshoot%7Clittleshoot-commons-id%7C1.0.3%7Cjar

Comment: this class only does version 4 uuid